# specify a range in bundler ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Is there a way to specify a range for ruby version?

```
ruby '~> 2.1.0'
Your Ruby version is 2.1.1, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.1.0

ruby '>= 2.1.0'
Your Ruby version is 2.1.1, but your Gemfile specified >= 2.1.0
```

Obviously, ranges works for gems, but maybe it's not possible for ruby version. Or did I get my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't set a range for the ruby version, [see here](http://bundler.io/v1.6/gemfile_ruby.html)

Syntax is like so:

```
ruby 'RUBY_VERSION', :engine => 'ENGINE', :engine_version => 'ENGINE_VERSION', :patchlevel => 'RUBY_PATCHLEVEL'
```

Comment: np, it was a logical thing to try.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Bundler 1.x because it cannot be done maintaining backward compatibility with the format of `Gemfile.lock`.

> As discussed there, this is arguably a bad idea unless the lockfile contains the ruby version. Adding the ruby version to the lockfile means Bundler 2 at the earliest.

(from  an [issue that has been filed requesting the addition of a *range* feature for Ruby versions](https://github.com/bundler/bundler-features/issues/13))