# Installing Tzinfo in gemfile using bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As mentioned, I tried to install the eventbrite-client, but it requires tzinfo and shows the following

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tzinfo":
  In Gemfile:
    eventbrite-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.22) ruby

    tzinfo (1.1.0)
```

No matter what I tried it is still the same, even a simple

```
gem install tzinfo
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Are you developing on Windows platform? Known issue w/ tzinfo.

Comment: No, Yosemite. The known issue on Windows is the 32/64 bit issue ?

Comment: Specifically a tzinfo loading problem: TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound Errors. I don't think it's a 32/64-bit related problem. Someone created a Github page on the topic with the problem described and the fix.  https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors. I hope this helps. If this is the answer, I'll re-post it as an answer, so other people can easily reference it with your question. Okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mean that your version of `eventbrite-client` gem depends to (compatible with) with specified version of `tzinfo` (i.e. ~> 0.3.22) but your Rails application using `tzinfo` with version `1.1.0`. So, you can't use two gems with different versions because it cause namespace conflict.

I recommend to create fork of `eventbrite-client` repository, bump `tzinfo` version and fix compatibility problems related to new version if they is exists. After that you can use customized version of `eventbrite-client` in your Rails project.

Comment: so ~>0.3.22 means >= 0.3.22 but < 0.4 ?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121960/why-does-the-gemfile-semantic-versioning-operator-produce-inconsistent-resu) is details.